# how to use Java library gabrielemariotti cardslib in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-cardview

Hello I have seen google cardview library at this location:
 https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

I am developing application with xamarin android, and willing to use this library in my application using C#, how would i use this in my project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can install the nuget library Support V7 Cardview, which you can find here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView/

An example how to use that is available on GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android_l/CardViewSample

If you really want to use the CardLib of Gabriele Mariotti, then you should create bindings for the cardslib before you can use it in C#. For more information on how to do that you can take a look at the Xamarin Documentation: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/

Comment: Thanks Martijn for answering my question, but i would like to use Gabriele Mariotti library in my project, I require JAR files, but its not available on their GitHub repository, how would i create JAR file from their project? I am .net guy so not much aware of Java things.

Comment: You need to download the project, import it into Eclipse, and generate a JAR with Gradle or some other build tool.

Comment: Ok Martijn I will check it out.

Comment: Hi @ChrisCook, i havent tried yet converting that cardslib to xamarin, but have got xamarin support library for cardview, so for now using that

Comment: Hi @Martijn , I have seen library https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations for listview animation and tried to convert to xamarin binding library, as provided 3 Jars with embeddedJars and 9oldandroids as embeddedreferenceJars, binding project compiled without any error, but it did not generate any binding , what could be the reason?

Comment: @Suketu don't use this thread for your problem. Rather open a new question so i can help you there.